# Elastalert 'spike' rule alerting on 0 events being greater than 0 events

Tags: elastalert

I am using elastalert HEAD as of today.

I am using this rule:

```
es_host: *******
es_port: 443
use_ssl: True
name: Mike Learning Two
type: spike
index: cwl-*
threshold: 2
timeframe:
  minutes: 1
spike_height: 2
spike_type: "up"
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "status:404"
alert:
- "debug"
```

And it does indeed detect spikes.  But sometimes it alerts with this message:

```
INFO:elastalert:Alert for Mike Learning Two at 2016-03-30T08:27:52.137927Z:
INFO:elastalert:Mike Learning Two

An abnormal number (0) of events occurred around 2016-03-30 08:27 UTC.
Preceding that time, there were only 0 events within 0:01:00

@timestamp: 2016-03-30T08:27:52.137927Z
reference_count: 0
spike_count: 0
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting no answer from SO, I posted an issue on the Elastalert Github.

https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/455

Their answer was:

> Yeah. I guess this is sort of a bug. You should set either
>   threshold_ref or threshold_cur instead of threshold. The example rule
>   is outdated and incorrect and not setting either value should result
>   in an error. My fault for neglecting it as the config format changed.